# Erro ao tentar usar o mysqli_fetch()

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando utilizar o mysqli_fetch() para transformar meu result do mysql em um array porém o php me retorna a seguinte mensagem: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch()

essa é a função que estou utilizando

```
public function PopulaPerfil()
{
    include("conexao.php");

    $cd = $_SESSION['cd_usuario'];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE cd_usuario = '$cd' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
    $resultArray= mysqli_fetch($result);
    return $resultArray;
    die();
}
```

Comment: Veja no seu php.ini se o mysqli esta ativado

Comment: Desculpa mas não entendi o que vc quis dizer com php.ini

Comment: php.ini é um arquivo de configuração do PHP. Ele fica nos diretorios do PHP do seu pc. Nele vc ativa e desativa modulos e extensões e aparentemente o seu modulo do mysqli está desativado (linha deve estar comentada).

Comment: @Reignomo Tenta substituir a função `mysqli_fetch` por `mysqli_fetch_all` ou `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: Dependendo da versão do seu php e dos modulos instalados voce tambem pode obter esse erro.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo @Reignomo A função `mysqli_fetch` está obsoleta desde a versão 5.4 do PHP

Comment: Vlw pessoal troquei para mysqli_fetch_array e funcionou :D

Comment: Boa @Piupz, eu não sabia. Não mexo em php há anos rs. Posta como resposta pro amigo dar como concluido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi comentado, a função [mysqli_fetch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-fetch.php) está obsoleta e foi removida desde a versão 5.4 do PHP.

Para isso pode ser utilizado a função [mysqli_fetch_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Exemplo:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Nesse exemplo irá ser retornado uma linha de resultado em forma de matriz associativa.